# Error reading config file. Golang using viper package

Tags: go, viper-go

please i need help in reading from an env.json file. Anytime i run my code i always get this error

> `Error reading config file, Config File "env" Not Found in "[/Users/franklynomonade/go/src/bitbucket.org/core_backend/cmd/server/bitbucket.org/core_backend/pkg/app/config]"`

`"/Users/franklynomonade/go/src/bitbucket.org/core_backend/cmd/server"` is the path where my main.go file is in, while `"bitbucket.org/core_backend/pkg/app/config"` is the path where the env.json file is located.
I believe the path where the env.json file should be read is `"bitbucket.org/core_backend/pkg/app/config"` and not `"/Users/franklynomonade/go/src/bitbucket.org/core_backend/cmd/server/bitbucket.org/core_backend/pkg/app/config"`

I am using `github.com/spf13/viper` package to read the env.json file.

[image: here is the code that reads from the env.json file]

```golang
func LoadConfig() {
    viper.AddConfigPath(myPath)

    viper.SetConfigName("env")

    viper.SetConfigType("json")

    // searches for config file in given paths and read it
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error reading config file: %s", err)
    }

    // confirm which config file is used
    log.Printf("Using s: %s\n", viper.ConfigFileUsed()
}
```

Any idea on how i can fix this?

Comment: Hi, maybe you can show some code of what you're doing? I'm not familiar with viper, but when reading files (for example using `ioutil.ReadFile`), it's relative to the folder you execute your application

Comment: @oren i just edited the question and added a sample of the code

Comment: It's probably related to your `myPath`. What its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relative or absolute paths, usually, it's better to use relative paths since you don't need to specify the path outside of your project.

When using the relative path, it searches the path relative to the folder in which you executed the binary.

Assuming this is the tree:

```
├── core_backend
│   ├── cmd
│   └── pkg
│       ├── api 
│       └── app
│            └── config
│                  └── env.json
```

Let's say you run your program in the `core_backend` directory, you would set your variable `myPath` to this value

```
"pkg/app/config"
```